# Issue with display div on hover of another div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get my description to show when i hover on the figcaption. I tried doing this with css by changing the opacity which the class:

```
.hoverForDesc:hover >#product1
```

which i found on SE but its not working at all when i hover now nothing happens and i dont know what the problem is.

```
<figure class="productCard">
  <div class="test_layer" id="product1">
    Description
  </div>
  <img src="http://www.altpress.com/images/uploads/news/Hello_Kitty.jpg" alt="product1" />
  <figcaption class="hoverForDesc">
    <div class="productText">
      <h3>Product name</h3>
      <p>subtitle <i class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
    </div>
    <div class="price">
      €1699,-
    </div>
  </figcaption>
</figure>
```

CSS

```
#product1{
  opacity: 0.0;
}

.hoverForDesc:hover >#product1{
  opacity: 1.0;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bk64sLa6/305/)

Comment: `.hoverForDesc:hover >#product1`this rule cannot work since `#product1` is not a descendant of `.hoverForDesc`

Comment: That rule would only work if `#product1` were nested within `.hoverForDesc`, and you can simply that rule further by just omitting the child combinator (`>`) from your selectors (e.g `.hoverForDesc:hover #product1`). Also, consider using class selectors instead of ID selectors; ID selectors should be unique and class selectors are intended for something like this (assuming you are declaring global styles).

Comment: Thanks I know what is going wrong at least lets see how to fix it

Comment: To be clear, do you need the description to appear when you hover over the product? e.g: `.productCard:hover #product1`, see: https://jsfiddle.net/bk64sLa6/306/

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError Thats close to what i wanted but i want the hover only to work when i hover on the figcaption (the part under the orange line) Im getting the result pretty much with js like this http://jsfiddle.net/bk64sLa6/309/ but i need to get it more smooth since its now not going smooth and reloading the hover effect every movement

Comment: Referring to your jsfiddle linked above, you just need to include `#product1` with the `.hover()` method selectors, e.g: https://jsfiddle.net/bk64sLa6/310/ Otherwise this will only apply when hovering over `#hover`, and as soon as `#product1` appears, you are now hovering over `product#1` - which will hide `#product1` again, leaving you hovering over `#hover` again, repeating the cycle...

Comment: Thanks cant mark it as anwer but you really helped me out!